# How to use rabbitmqctl to connect to the rabbitmqserver in the docker container?

Tags: rabbitmq, docker, rabbitmqctl

I've used docker to start my rabbitmqserver. How can I use rabbitmqctl to connect to the rabbitmqserver in the docker container?

Port 5672 has been exposed and map to the 5672 port of my host. But I still get the following error:

```
Status of node rabbit@m2 ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@m2: nodedown
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rabbitmqctl` uses [Erlang Distributed Protocol](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) (EDP) to communicate with RabbitMQ. Port 5672 provides AMQP protocol. You can investigate EDP port that your RabbitMQ instance uses:

```
$ netstat -uptan | grep beam
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55950           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31446/beam.smp  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31446/beam.smp  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31446/beam.smp  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55096         127.0.0.1:4369          ESTABLISHED 31446/beam.smp  
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      31446/beam.smp
```

It means that RabbitMQ:

- connected to [EPMD (Erlang Port Mapper Daemon)](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html) on 127.0.0.1:4369 to make nodes able to see each other
- waits for incoming EDP connection on port 55950
- waits for AMQP connection on port 5672 and 55672
- waits for incoming [HTTP management](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) connection on port 15672

To make `rabbitmqctl` able to connect to RabbitMQ you also have to forward port 55950 and allow RabbitMQ instance connect to 127.0.0.1:4369.
It is possible that RabbitMQ EDP port is dinamic, so to make it static you can try to use `ERL_EPMD_PORT` variable of [Erlang environment variables](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) or use `inet_dist_listen_min` and `inet_dist_listen_max` of [Erlang Kernel configuration options](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html) and apply it with [RabbitMQ environment variable](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) - `export RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE="/path/to/my_rabbitmq.conf`

my_rabbitmq.conf

```
[{kernel,[{inet_dist_listen_min, 55950},{inet_dist_listen_min, 55950}]}].
```

Or you can use [RabbitMQ Management Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html). It is more functional and simple to setup.

Comment: How can "allow RabbitMQ instance connect to 127.0.0.1:4369" be achieved with Docker? So far I have the following options:

`-p 55950:55950 -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -e ERL_EPMD_PORT=55950`

when running the docker container, and I have `epmd` running on the host. But still, I can't connect with `rabbitmqctl` to the Rabbit instance in the container.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your container is called `rabbitmq` and is running:

```
docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Answer (score 0):

**I got this error trying to setup RabbitMQ on a cluster on an ubuntu and fedora machine:**

```
el@apollo:/etc/rabbitmq$ sudo rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@192.168.1.8
Clustering node rabbit@apollo with 'rabbit@192.168.1.8' ...
Error: unable to connect to nodes ['rabbit@192.168.1.8']: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@192.168.1.8']

rabbit@192.168.1.8:
  * unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on 192.168.1.8: address 
    (cannot connect to host/port)


current node details:
- node name: rabbitmqctl7233@apollo
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: g0tS9zEdo7OEDSZaDTGirA==
```

**I was able to eliminate this error by opening the 4369 and 59984 port on the 192.168.1.8 machine that is one of the slave nodes of the cluster:**

```
el@defiant ~ $ su -
Password:
[root@defiant ~]# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4369 --syn -j ACCEPT
[root@defiant ~]# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 59984 --syn -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Can you explain why opening port 59984 helped?

Answer (score 0):

Port 4369 was not enabled on firewall. When I switched firewall 'off'. Everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `docker exec -t rabbitmq sh`
Then you will get access to the terminal of your docker environment.

Once you are in, type `rabbitmqctl` to see if it works

Hopefully it can help you.

Comment: This did not work for me, however `docker exec -ti rabbitmq bash -c "su -"` did, although rabbitmqctl was an unknown command once there